# vs2003: how to stop build at the first error

Tags: visual-studio

So as I attempt to build a huge solution with about 200+ projects..

1. How do I stop the build at the very first error instead of waiting till the whole build is finished.
2. Where do I read the log of the build or the output of the build?
3. If I am able to stop the build at first error, where is the file located so I could read that error.

At this point, I can not change the solution file in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do Ctrl + Break (this cancels the build process).
Though you'll have to watch the Output windows to see if an error occured.

You can view the log of the build results/progress from the Output window (be sure the Build option is selected).

Comment: Great idea, but sometimes Visual Studio just does not respond to Ctrl+Break command and builds and builds and builds for eternity!

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can find REAL answer here:

[Visual Studio option - Stop on any project error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976399/visual-studio-option-stop-on-any-project-error)

To add some value to it:

When running 'test' builds, turn concurrent builds option down to ONE!  Else, it will stop the build on first error, but will wait for all parallel builds to complete.  And will clutter your output window.