# Visual Studio option - Stop on any project error

Tags: visual-studio, ide, build

Is there any way in VS that I can make it stop building the solution if ANY project in the build step fails to build?

I have a solution that has cca. 100 projects.  I want build process to STOP if it encounters build error on any of the projects.

Failing build means that there were build errors while building that project.

Comment: When you say "stop" what do you mean?  Right now if you're building and one fails it will report it.  Do you want it to bale at that point, do you have mult-startup projects?  Do you want it to clear out all the "built" projects that could have been built before the failure.  Also please define fail - is it unit tests, style/fxcop or just a straight build.

Comment: I think he wants to stop the whole building process if there is at least one project that failed to build, just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fancy faffing with VB macros, have a look at this [eHow article](http://www.ehow.com/how_5025041_automatically-visual-studio-build-error.html) that tells you how to do just that.

Comment: That's not faffing, it's just copypasting :)  They are worse things then little VBScript.  works like a charm